# Best machine learning algorithm for binary and numeric independent variables and numeric dependent variable?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm not sure which machine learning algorithm is best to use with a dataset of 5 binary (yes and no) and 1 numerical (hours) independent variables and a numerical dependent variable?

The outcome is the weight difference after 6 months based on lifestyle choices during that period (smoking, sugar-free diet etc.) and time spent in fitness.

Is the regression tree algorithm suitable for this or would you recommend something entirely different?

Comment: Stuff like CART (classification and regression trees) might be worth a go to see what happens. Might at least tell you if all the binary variables are needed/relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Regression Tree (Decision Tree):**

   - A Regression Tree is suitable for both numeric and binary input variables. It can handle non-linear relationships between features and the target variable. Decision Trees partition the data into subsets based on features, making them useful for understanding feature importance and creating interpretable models.
2. **Random Forest:**

   - Random Forest is an ensemble method that uses multiple decision trees and averages their predictions to improve accuracy and reduce overfitting. It can handle both numeric and binary features and is robust against noise and outliers. Random Forests often perform well on a variety of datasets and don't require extensive feature engineering.
3. **Gradient Boosting:**

   - Gradient Boosting is another ensemble method that combines weak learners (usually decision trees) to build a strong predictive model. It can handle mixed data types and automatically handle feature interactions. Gradient Boosting is known for its high accuracy and ability to handle complex relationships between features and the target variable.

Remember that there is no one-size-fits-all solution, so try a couple different algorithms and compare their performance to make a decision. Also, consider the interpretability of the models, as it may be important in understanding the factors influencing weight difference in your specific domain.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jon! I'll try out the Random Forest and Gradient Boosting Algorithms on top of the standard regression tree algorithm!

Answer (score 0):

First, maybe you try to evaluate this questions:

**1.** What is your data volume? Is it >10³, >10⁶or 10⁹?

**2.** Are there outliers?

If you have a smaller amount of data, the models [Random Forest and Support Vector Machine](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) can be very good, both for regression and classification tasks.
As you have both categorical and numeric variables, you can sometimes use the one-hot-encode technique to handle categorical variables. Generally when mixing in the training data, integer values with floats, the model may not respond as well as we consider only one of the cases.
This is because many algorithms use different strategies to treat discrete values and floats (real numbers).

Other points that are recommended, test some models on your problem and evaluate the metric. There is a famous theorem called ["no free lunch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) which states that there is no way to know a priori (before testing) which model will be the best for your data set.

Anyway, models that tend to solve a wide range of problems very well are Random Forest, SVM, [XGBoost and LightGBM](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lightgbm-vs-xgboost-which-algorithm-is-better/) (to name just 4).